# completionBlock error handling

Tags: ios, parsing, error-handling

I am trying to handle the `completionBlock` error and catch it if there is any exception.

Following is my code:

```
ParseOperation *parser = [[ParseOperation alloc] initWithData:self.appListData];
if([[ParseOperation alloc] initWithData:self.appListData] == nil)
    NSLog(@"[[ParseOperation alloc] initWithData:self.appListData] is nill");
__weak ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;
parser.completionBlock = ^(void) {
    if (weakParser.appRecordList) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
            rootViewController.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
            if(weakParser.appRecordList == nil)
                 NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList is nill");
            if(weakParser.appRecordList != nil)
                NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList is Not nill");
            [rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
    self.queue = nil;
};
```

I implemented the following in my class to get the error result on the console:

```
parser.errorHandler = ^(NSError *parseError) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self handleError:parseError];
        NSLog(@"[self handleError:parseError] %@", parseError);
    });
};
```

`weakParser.appRecordList` returns `nil` most of the time (case of error).

Is the problem inside the `ParseOperation` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you need to add **__block** before weakParser, otherwise, when completion block is running, there will be no reference to the *weakParser*.
Please note that variables are assigned to block at the moment of the declaration, and if they are not set as **__block**, their value will be passed to the blocks (as opposed to there pointer a.k.a. reference) and because it is a weak reference in your case, when it gets to the bottom of the method, it will be released and block never gets the chance to act on it.
Hope this helps: [Apple Programming Guide: Working with blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

**[Edit]** P.S.: I'm not sure but I think removing **__weak** from weakParser may solve the problem too.

Comment: intersting fact if i delete __weak part or changes it to __block both way it works ! and another thing is this is pure sample from Apple site . kinda confused why it should be there o.O

Comment: they both do the same thing @AndreyMarkov, __block passes a reference to weakParser to block and therefore retains a strong reference to it in block and prevents it from being released, deleting the __weak makes it a strong reference and does the same thing (for retaining point of view), these two approaches are different in a few parts, it is better practice to use __block, it makes it easier to read and you can change the parameter in the block. Apple samples are not flawless, and it might have meant something different. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is something about __weak using in block, following code help the dispatch method to pass the `appRecordList` value:

```
id appRecordList = weakParser.appRecordList;
if (appRecordList) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
            rootViewController.entries = appRecordList;
            if(appRecordList== nil)
                 NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList is nill");
            if(appRecordList != nil)
                NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList is Not nill");
            [rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
```